# Android NDK app crashes on first call to prebuilt shared library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, cmake, shared-libraries

I am trying to build an Android app based on OpenCV for Tegra example code.  I am adding a prebuilt library for aruco to handle marker tracking.  When I make my first call to code in libaruco.so the app crashes with (logcat)

```
A/libc(4669): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x0000123d (code=-6), thread 4909 (Thread-453)
```

- working on Windows 7/x64
- Eclipse Luna
- Android r10d NDK
- OpenCV-2.4.8.2-Tegra-sdk
- OpenCV Manager on Android device

I have built the aruco library and utility programs previously for Windows using CMake.

I used CMake with an Android toolchain file (derived from android-cmake) to build the shared library.  Used cmake-gui to set things I needed such as location of OpenCV and ANDROID_NDK.  Using GNU 4.8 toolchain arm-Linux-androideabi-4.8, target of armeabi-v7a.  The toolchain originally used postfix version numbers to build libaruco.so, libaruco.so.1.2, and libaruco.so.1.2.3.  I commented out VERSION and SOVERSION in CMakeLists.txt to end up with a single libaruco.so as shared library.

The shared library builds with no apparent errors.

I have an Android project in Eclipse based on an OpenCV sample project with native support.  I have JNIEXPORT calls in my C++ code (have done this before).  I reference the libaruco.so as a prebuilt shared library in my android.mk and load the library in java after OpenCV loads and before loading my native application library.

```
private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization

                // aruco shared library
                System.loadLibrary("aruco");
                Log.i(TAG, "aruco loaded successfully");

                // native application shared libary
                System.loadLibrary("aruco_test_board");
                Log.i(TAG, "aruco_test_board loaded successfully");

                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};
```

Everything builds with no errors.  I can run the app on my device (tablet running Android 4.4.2) and logcat shows that the libraries were loaded and that preview images are being handled.  I can make calls to my native code that do not reference libaruco.so.

As soon as I call to any code in libaruco.so from my native code the app crashes with the SIGABRT line shown above.

To reiterate - I have built native projects successfully, and used OpenCV for Android, so I know how those parts work.  The problem is using this prebuilt shared library.

Is there any way to test the libaruco.so shared library outside of running it on Android to see if it is compatible with my native project?

Any other advice on using a toolchain with CMake to build libraries for Android?

Both my project native code and the libaruco.so code are built using the same compiler from the NDK, same settings for APP_ABI, APP_STL, flags, etc.  The only difference is that one is built using CMake and one is built by Eclipse.

Full logcat output:

```
04-14 13:40:31.135: I/art(6393): CheckJNI enabled: not enabling JNI app bug workarounds.
04-14 13:40:31.171: I/ArucoTestBoard(6393): Instantiated new class com.gdeb.sparky.aruco_test_board.ArucoTestBoardActivity
04-14 13:40:31.177: I/ArucoTestBoard(6393): called onCreate
04-14 13:40:31.193: D/CameraBridge(6393): Attr count: 3
04-14 13:40:31.198: W/ContextImpl(6393): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=org.opencv.engine.BIND } android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:517 org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper.initOpenCV:24 org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader.initAsync:74 
04-14 13:40:31.274: D/CameraBridge(6393): call surfaceChanged event
04-14 13:40:31.470: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): Service connection created
04-14 13:40:31.478: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): Trying to get library path
04-14 13:40:31.568: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): Trying to get library list
04-14 13:40:31.591: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): Library list: ""
04-14 13:40:31.591: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): First attempt to load libs
04-14 13:40:31.591: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): Trying to init OpenCV libs
04-14 13:40:31.592: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): Trying to load library /data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-1/libopencv_java.so
04-14 13:40:31.617: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): OpenCV libs init was ok!
04-14 13:40:31.617: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): First attempt to load libs is OK
04-14 13:40:31.620: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.8.2 =====================================
04-14 13:40:31.620: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   Version control:               2.4.8.2
04-14 13:40:31.620: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   Platform:
04-14 13:40:31.620: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Host:                        Linux 3.2.0-56-generic x86_64
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Target:                      Linux 1 armv7-a
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     CMake:                       2.8.12.1
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     CMake generator:             Ninja
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     CMake build tool:            /usr/local/bin/ninja
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Configuration:               Release
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   C/C++:
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     C++ Compiler:                /opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++  (ver 4.6)
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     C++ flags (Release):         -fexceptions -frtti -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fpic -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -fweb -fwrapv -frename-registers -fsched2-use-superblocks -fsched2-use-traces -fsched-stalled-insns-dep=100 -fsched-stalled-insns=2 -fno-tree-vectorize   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -mthumb -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     C++ flags (Debug):           -fexceptions -frtti -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fpic -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -fweb -fwrapv -frename-registers -fsched2-use-superblocks -fsched2-use-traces -fsched-stalled-insns-dep=100 -fsched-stalled-insns=2 -fno-tree-vectorize   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -marm -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O0 -g -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     C Compiler:                  /opt/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     C flags (Release):           -fexceptions -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fpic -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -fweb -fwrapv -frename-registers -fsched2-use-superblocks -fsched2-use-traces -fsched-stalled-insns-dep=100 -fsched-stalled-insns=2 -fno-tree-vectorize   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -mthumb -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     C flags (Debug):             -fexceptions -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r8c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -fpic -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -fweb -fwrapv -frename-registers -fsched2-use-superblocks -fsched2-use-traces -fsched-stalled-insns-dep=100 -fsched-stalled-insns=2 -fno-tree-vectorize   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpu=neon -marm -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O0 -g -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Precompiled headers:         NO
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   OpenCV modules:
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     To be built:                 core androidcamera flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d ml objdetect video contrib photo java dynamicuda legacy gpu ocl stitching ts videostab
04-14 13:40:31.625: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Disabled:                    world
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Disabled by dependency:      -
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Unavailable:                 nonfree python superres facedetect imuvstab tegra vstab
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   Android: 
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Android ABI:                 armeabi-v7a with NEON
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     STL type:                    gnustl_static
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Native API level:            android-9
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     SDK target:                  android-11
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Android NDK:                 /opt/android-ndk-r8c (toolchain: arm-linux-androideabi-4.6)
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     android tool:                /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android (Android SDK Tools, revision 22.3.)
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Google Play package:         YES
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Android examples:            YES
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   GUI: 
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     GTK+ 2.x:                    NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     GThread :                    NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     GtkGlExt:                    NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     OpenGL support:              NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   Media I/O: 
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     ZLib:                        z (ver 1.2.3)
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     JPEG:                        build (ver 62)
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.12)
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   Video I/O:
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     AndroidNativeCamera:         YES, use prebuilt libraries
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   Other third-party libraries:
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Use IPP:                     NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.1.2)
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Use TBB:                     YES (ver 4.1 interface 6102)
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Use OpenMP:                  NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Use GCD                      NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Use Concurrency              NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Use C=:                      NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 6.0)
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Use OpenCL:                  YES
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   NVIDIA CUDA
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Use CUFFT:                   YES
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Use CUBLAS:                  NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     USE NVCUVID:                 NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     NVIDIA GPU arch:             32
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     NVIDIA PTX archs:
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Use fast math:               NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   OpenCL:
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Version:                     dynamic
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Include path:                /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Use AMD FFT:                 NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Use AMD BLAS:                NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   Python:
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2 (ver 2.7.3)
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   Java:
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.8.2)
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Java tests:                  YES
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   Documentation:
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Build Documentation:         YES
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Sphinx:                      /usr/local/bin/sphinx-build (ver 1.1.3)
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     PdfLaTeX compiler:           /usr/bin/pdflatex
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   Tests and samples:
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Tests:                       YES
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     Performance tests:           YES
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):     C/C++ Examples:              NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   Install path:                  /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/build/builds/o4t/install
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/build/builds/o4t
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): -----------------------------------------------------------------
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): General configuration for OpenCV4Tegra =====================================
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   inner version                  2.4.8.2
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   memory allocator               YES
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   hardware link                  YES
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   compact sources                YES
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393):   logging enabled                NO
04-14 13:40:31.626: I/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): -----------------------------------------------------------------
04-14 13:40:31.626: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): Init finished with status 0
04-14 13:40:31.627: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): Unbind from service
04-14 13:40:31.628: D/OpenCVManager/Helper(6393): Calling using callback
04-14 13:40:31.628: I/ArucoTestBoard(6393): OpenCV loaded successfully
04-14 13:40:31.649: I/ArucoTestBoard(6393): aruco loaded successfully
04-14 13:40:31.650: I/ArucoTestBoard(6393): aruco_test_board loaded successfully
04-14 13:40:31.650: D/JavaCameraView(6393): Connecting to camera
04-14 13:40:31.650: D/JavaCameraView(6393): Initialize java camera
04-14 13:40:31.650: D/JavaCameraView(6393): Trying to open camera with old open()
04-14 13:40:31.744: D/JavaCameraView(6393): getSupportedPreviewSizes()
04-14 13:40:31.745: D/JavaCameraView(6393): Set preview size to 1920x1080
04-14 13:40:31.749: D/libEGL(6393): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
04-14 13:40:31.749: I/(6393): Attempting to load EGL implementation libEGL_tegra_impl
04-14 13:40:31.752: I/(6393): Loaded EGL implementation libEGL_tegra_impl
04-14 13:40:31.761: D/libEGL(6393): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
04-14 13:40:31.763: D/libEGL(6393): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
04-14 13:40:31.869: I/(6393): Loading GLESv2 implementation libGLESv2_tegra_impl
04-14 13:40:31.872: E/libEGL(6393): validate_display:254 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
04-14 13:40:31.877: D/JavaCameraView(6393): startPreview
04-14 13:40:31.971: D/JavaCameraView(6393): Starting processing thread
04-14 13:40:32.158: D/JavaCameraView(6393): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 3110400
04-14 13:40:32.232: D/CameraBridge(6393): mStretch value: 1.0
04-14 13:40:32.357: D/JavaCameraView(6393): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 3110400
04-14 13:40:32.406: D/CameraBridge(6393): mStretch value: 1.0
04-14 13:40:37.667: D/JavaCameraView(6393): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 3110400
04-14 13:40:37.688: D/CameraBridge(6393): mStretch value: 1.0
04-14 13:40:37.767: D/JavaCameraView(6393): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 3110400
04-14 13:40:37.789: D/CameraBridge(6393): mStretch value: 1.0
04-14 13:40:37.871: D/JavaCameraView(6393): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 3110400
04-14 13:40:37.883: I/ArucoTestBoard(6393): would be GetStatus()
04-14 13:40:37.907: D/CameraBridge(6393): mStretch value: 1.0
04-14 13:40:37.971: D/JavaCameraView(6393): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 3110400
04-14 13:40:37.998: D/CameraBridge(6393): mStretch value: 1.0
04-14 13:40:38.075: I/ArucoTestBoard(6393): called onOptionsItemSelected; selected item: Init Camera
04-14 13:40:38.075: D/JavaCameraView(6393): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 3110400
04-14 13:40:38.078: I/ArucoTestBoard(6393): calling InitCamera(), 1920, 1080
04-14 13:40:38.080: I/ArucoTestBoard(6393): started InitCamera()
04-14 13:40:38.084: A/libc(6393): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000018f9 (code=-6), thread 6547 (Thread-615)
04-14 13:40:38.099: D/CameraBridge(6393): mStretch value: 1.0
```

Java code where it aborts:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    final int viewMode = mViewMode;
    switch (viewMode) {
    case VIEW_MODE_INIT:
        Log.i(TAG, "calling InitCamera(), " + mWidth + ", " + mHeight);
        //InitCamera(mWidth, mHeight);

          // long running init of camera
          Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              InitCamera(mWidth, mHeight);
              mInitCameraDone = true;
            }
          };
          new Thread(runnable).start();
        Log.i(TAG, "started InitCamera()");

        // Reset view mode
        mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_RGBA;
        break;
    }
```

InitCamera(int, int) is native code in this project.  If I do not call to the shared library from InitCamera() the app runs.  As soon as I call to the shared library I get SIGABRT.

From ndk-stack dump of stack trace:

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'google/tango/yellowstone:4.4.2/KOT49H.150309/150309002:user/release-keys'
pid: 6393, tid: 6547, name: Thread-615  >>> com.gdeb.sparky.aruco_test_board <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  161):     #00  pc 00021f78  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  161):     #01  pc 0001300d  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  161):     #02  pc 00013221  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  161):     #03  pc 00011f57  /system/lib/libc.so
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  161):     #04  pc 0002182c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
Stack frame I/DEBUG   (  161):     #05  pc 0028be24  /data/app-lib/com.gdeb.sparky.aruco_test_board-1/libaruco.so (__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()+344): Routine ??
??:0
Crash dump is complete
```

Comment: Show the whole native crash log and surrounding java-level messages, not just one line.

Comment: Looks like a nullptr exception.

Comment: Added longer logcat dump and the related java code.

Comment: Yes, but where is the native stack trace?  That's what will let you figure out what was happening there.  Otherwise will have to look the fault address up in the libc load map and figure it out yourself.

Comment: Sorry, native stack trace was new to me.  Added to post.  Doesn't mean much to me.

Comment: *"As soon as I call to the shared library"* - what exactly happens there? You shared a snippet of Java code, but it is not clear what native code does and what call you make *or skip* there?

Comment: Unbelievable.  The first call to the shared library happens to be a routine that reads a configuration file from the file system.  As it turns out, I did not have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions set in my AndroidManifest.xml file.  Adding permission got me past this error.  Of course, the next problem that popped up in the library code caused the same error message, with the same lack of information.  I am off to figure out how to run the debugger in Eclipse.

Comment: @Ken , I see you are fighting with similar issues like I am in my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920364/cython-buildable-python-binded-c-code-to-download-file-via-http-rest-api . Would you like yto connect via chat and discuss the matters there? I am eager to learn and to help on such issue.